# passing solace message using events

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, solace

I am trying to publish a solace message to a topic and then after receiving it in the subscriber, the subscriber sends this message via events to another part of my application for further processing. This is all happening in one node.js process. I know it might be the best practice way of doing things so feel free to point me in a better direction. I know instead of events, I can use message queues but I'd like to see if this can be down with events.

I have the following files:
**server.js**: server init code
**TopicPublisher.js**: publishes a solace message to a topic
**TopicSubscriber.js**: subscribes to a solace topic to consume messages then emits an event with the message contents
**SocketWrapper.js**: receives the event emitted by `TopicSubscriber.js` and does further processing

### server.js

```
function initServer() {
    const express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        server = require('http').createServer(app);
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

    const SocketWrapper = require('./SocketWrapper');
    let sockets = new Set();

    //This example emits to individual sockets (track by sockets Set above).
    //Could also add sockets to a "room" as well using socket.join('roomId')
    //https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-join-room-callback

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

    /*
    everytime there is a new connection, there is a new socket
    */
    io.on('connection', socket => {

        sockets.add(socket);
        //add socket to heartbeatGenerator as well
        socketWrapper.sockets.add(socket);
        console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} added`);

        socket.on('clientdata', data => {
            console.log(data);
        });

        if (!socketWrapper.started) {
            socketWrapper.start();
        }

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`Deleting socket: ${socket.id}`);
            sockets.delete(socket);
            console.log(`Remaining sockets: ${sockets.size}`);
        });

    });

    server.listen(8080);
    console.log('Visit http://localhost:8080 in your browser');

}

initServer();
//1000ms to ensure async behaviors perform in a sync manner
require('./solace/TopicSubscriber', 1000);
//1500ms to ensure async behaviors perform in a sync manner
setTimeout(() => { require('./solace/TopicPublisher');}, 1500);
```

I know the `setTimeout()` approach is hacky.. just trying to get this version working.

### TopicSubscriber.js

```
const solace = require('solclientjs').debug; // logging supported
const eventEmitter = require('../EventEmitter');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Initialize factory with the most recent API defaults
const factoryProps = new solace.SolclientFactoryProperties();
factoryProps.profile = solace.SolclientFactoryProfiles.version10;
solace.SolclientFactory.init(factoryProps);

// enable logging to JavaScript console at WARN level
// NOTICE: works only with ('solclientjs').debug
solace.SolclientFactory.setLogLevel(solace.LogLevel.WARN);

const TopicSubscriber = function (solaceModule, topicName) {
    'use strict';
    const solace = solaceModule;
    const subscriber = {};
    subscriber.session = null;
    subscriber.topicName = topicName;
    subscriber.subscribed = false;

    // Logger
    subscriber.log = function (line) {
        const now = new Date();
        const time = [('0' + now.getHours()).slice(-2), ('0' + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        ('0' + now.getSeconds()).slice(-2)];
        const timestamp = '[' + time.join(':') + '] ';
        console.log(timestamp + line);
    };

    subscriber.log('\n*** Subscriber to topic "' + subscriber.topicName + '" is ready to connect ***');

    // main function
    subscriber.run = function (argv) {
        subscriber.connect(argv);
    };

    // Establishes connection to Solace message router
    subscriber.connect = function (argv) {
        if (subscriber.session !== null) {
            subscriber.log('Already connected and ready to subscribe.');
            return;
        }
        // extract params
        if (argv.length < 3) { // expecting 3 real arguments
            subscriber.log('Cannot connect: expecting all arguments' +
                ' <protocol://host[:port]> <client-username>@<message-vpn> <client-password>.\n' +
                'Available protocols are ws://, wss://, http://, https://, tcp://, tcps://');
            process.exit();
        }
        const hosturl = argv[0];
        subscriber.log('Connecting to Solace message router using url: ' + hosturl);
        const usernamevpn = argv[1];
        const username = usernamevpn.split('@')[0];
        subscriber.log('Client username: ' + username);
        const vpn = usernamevpn.split('@')[1];
        subscriber.log('Solace message router VPN name: ' + vpn);
        const pass = argv[2];
        // create session
        try {
            subscriber.session = solace.SolclientFactory.createSession({
                // solace.SessionProperties
                url: hosturl,
                vpnName: vpn,
                userName: username,
                password: pass,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            subscriber.log(error.toString());
        }
        // define session event listeners
        subscriber.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.UP_NOTICE, function (sessionEvent) {
            subscriber.log('=== Successfully connected and ready to subscribe. ===');
            subscriber.subscribe();
        });
        subscriber.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.CONNECT_FAILED_ERROR, function (sessionEvent) {
            subscriber.log('Connection failed to the message router: ' + sessionEvent.infoStr +
                ' - check correct parameter values and connectivity!');
        });
        subscriber.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.DISCONNECTED, function (sessionEvent) {
            subscriber.log('Disconnected.');
            subscriber.subscribed = false;
            if (subscriber.session !== null) {
                subscriber.session.dispose();
                subscriber.session = null;
            }
        });
        subscriber.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR, function (sessionEvent) {
            subscriber.log('Cannot subscribe to topic: ' + sessionEvent.correlationKey);
        });
        subscriber.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.SUBSCRIPTION_OK, function (sessionEvent) {
            if (subscriber.subscribed) {
                subscriber.subscribed = false;
                subscriber.log('Successfully unsubscribed from topic: ' + sessionEvent.correlationKey);
            } else {
                subscriber.subscribed = true;
                subscriber.log('Successfully subscribed to topic: ' + sessionEvent.correlationKey);
                subscriber.log('=== Ready to receive messages. ===');
            }
        });
        // define message event listener
        subscriber.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.MESSAGE, function (message) {
            subscriber.log('Received message: "' + message.getBinaryAttachment() + '", details:\n' +
                message.dump());

            //TODO: where the event emitting occurs
            const eventStatus = eventEmitter.emit('heartbeat-msg', message.getBinaryAttachment());
            console.log(`eventStatus: ${eventStatus}`);
        });
        // connect the session
        try {
            subscriber.session.connect();
        } catch (error) {
            subscriber.log(error.toString());
        }
    };

    // Subscribes to topic on Solace message router
    subscriber.subscribe = function () {
        if (subscriber.session !== null) {
            if (subscriber.subscribed) {
                subscriber.log('Already subscribed to "' + subscriber.topicName
                    + '" and ready to receive messages.');
            } else {
                subscriber.log('Subscribing to topic: ' + subscriber.topicName);
                try {
                    subscriber.session.subscribe(
                        solace.SolclientFactory.createTopicDestination(subscriber.topicName),
                        true, // generate confirmation when subscription is added successfully
                        subscriber.topicName, // use topic name as correlation key
                        10000 // 10 seconds timeout for this operation
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    subscriber.log(error.toString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            subscriber.log('Cannot subscribe because not connected to Solace message router.');
        }
    };

    subscriber.exit = function () {
        subscriber.unsubscribe();
        subscriber.disconnect();
        setTimeout(function () {
            process.exit();
        }, 1000); // wait for 1 second to finish
    };

    // Unsubscribes from topic on Solace message router
    subscriber.unsubscribe = function () {
        if (subscriber.session !== null) {
            if (subscriber.subscribed) {
                subscriber.log('Unsubscribing from topic: ' + subscriber.topicName);
                try {
                    subscriber.session.unsubscribe(
                        solace.SolclientFactory.createTopicDestination(subscriber.topicName),
                        true, // generate confirmation when subscription is removed successfully
                        subscriber.topicName, // use topic name as correlation key
                        10000 // 10 seconds timeout for this operation
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    subscriber.log(error.toString());
                }
            } else {
                subscriber.log('Cannot unsubscribe because not subscribed to the topic "'
                    + subscriber.topicName + '"');
            }
        } else {
            subscriber.log('Cannot unsubscribe because not connected to Solace message router.');
        }
    };

    // Gracefully disconnects from Solace message router
    subscriber.disconnect = function () {
        subscriber.log('Disconnecting from Solace message router...');
        if (subscriber.session !== null) {
            try {
                subscriber.session.disconnect();
            } catch (error) {
                subscriber.log(error.toString());
            }
        } else {
            subscriber.log('Not connected to Solace message router.');
        }
    };

    return subscriber;
};

const connectionArgs = []; //not provided for security reasons
subscriber.run(connectionArgs);


process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    'use strict';
    subscriber.exit();
});
```

Search for the string `//TODO: where the event emitting occurs` to find the relevant part of code.

### TopicPublisher.js

```
const TopicPublisher = function (solaceModule, topicName) {
    'use strict';
    const solace = solaceModule;
    const publisher = {};
    publisher.session = null;
    publisher.topicName = topicName;

    // Logger
    publisher.log = function (line) {
        const now = new Date();
        const time = [('0' + now.getHours()).slice(-2), ('0' + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        ('0' + now.getSeconds()).slice(-2)];
        const timestamp = '[' + time.join(':') + '] ';
        console.log(timestamp + line);
    };

    publisher.log('\n*** Publisher to topic "' + publisher.topicName + '" is ready to connect ***');

    // main function
    publisher.run = function (argv) {
        publisher.connect(argv);
    };

    // Establishes connection to Solace message router
    publisher.connect = function (argv) {
        if (publisher.session !== null) {
            publisher.log('Already connected and ready to publish.');
            return;
        }
        // extract params
        if (argv.length < 3) { // expecting 3 real arguments
            publisher.log('Cannot connect: expecting all arguments' +
                ' <protocol://host[:port]> <client-username>@<message-vpn> <client-password>.\n' +
                'Available protocols are ws://, wss://, http://, https://, tcp://, tcps://');
            process.exit();
        }
        const hosturl = argv[0];
        publisher.log('Connecting to Solace message router using url: ' + hosturl);
        const usernamevpn = argv[1];
        const username = usernamevpn.split('@')[0];
        publisher.log('Client username: ' + username);
        const vpn = usernamevpn.split('@')[1];
        publisher.log('Solace message router VPN name: ' + vpn);
        const pass = argv[2];
        // create session
        try {
            publisher.session = solace.SolclientFactory.createSession({
                // solace.SessionProperties
                url: hosturl,
                vpnName: vpn,
                userName: username,
                password: pass,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            publisher.log(error.toString());
        }
        // define session event listeners
        publisher.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.UP_NOTICE, function (sessionEvent) {
            publisher.log('=== Successfully connected and ready to publish messages. ===');
            publisher.publish();
            publisher.exit();
        });
        publisher.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.CONNECT_FAILED_ERROR, function (sessionEvent) {
            publisher.log('Connection failed to the message router: ' + sessionEvent.infoStr +
                ' - check correct parameter values and connectivity!');
        });
        publisher.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.DISCONNECTED, function (sessionEvent) {
            publisher.log('Disconnected.');
            if (publisher.session !== null) {
                publisher.session.dispose();
                publisher.session = null;
            }
        });
        // connect the session
        try {
            publisher.session.connect();
        } catch (error) {
            publisher.log(error.toString());
        }
    };

    // Publishes one message
    publisher.publish = function () {
        if (publisher.session !== null) {
            //NOTE: where to change sample message
            const messageText = 'SOM: 0';
            const message = solace.SolclientFactory.createMessage();
            message.setDestination(solace.SolclientFactory.createTopicDestination(publisher.topicName));
            message.setBinaryAttachment(messageText);
            message.setDeliveryMode(solace.MessageDeliveryModeType.DIRECT);
            publisher.log('Publishing message "' + messageText + '" to topic "' + publisher.topicName + '"...');
            try {
                publisher.session.send(message);
                publisher.log('Message published.');
            } catch (error) {
                publisher.log(error.toString());
            }
        } else {
            publisher.log('Cannot publish because not connected to Solace message router.');
        }
    };

    publisher.exit = function () {
        publisher.disconnect();
        //setTimeout(function () {
        //    process.exit();
        //}, 1000); // wait for 1 second to finish
    };

    // Gracefully disconnects from Solace message router
    publisher.disconnect = function () {
        publisher.log('Disconnecting from Solace message router...');
        if (publisher.session !== null) {
            try {
                publisher.session.disconnect();
            } catch (error) {
                publisher.log(error.toString());
            }
        } else {
            publisher.log('Not connected to Solace message router.');
        }
    };

    return publisher;
};

const solace = require('solclientjs').debug; // logging supported
const fs = require('fs');
// Initialize factory with the most recent API defaults
const factoryProps = new solace.SolclientFactoryProperties();
factoryProps.profile = solace.SolclientFactoryProfiles.version10;
solace.SolclientFactory.init(factoryProps);

// enable logging to JavaScript console at WARN level
// NOTICE: works only with ('solclientjs').debug
solace.SolclientFactory.setLogLevel(solace.LogLevel.WARN);

// create the publisher, specifying the name of the subscription topic
const publisher = new TopicPublisher(solace, 'tutorial/topic');

//TODO: remove single service approach?
const connectionArgs = []; //removed for security reasons
publisher.run(connectionArgs);
```

### SocketWrapper.js

```
const eventEmitter = require('./EventEmitter');

class SocketWrapper {
    constructor(ECNs) {
        this.started = false;
        this.ECNs = ECNs;
        this.sockets = new Set();
    }

    start() {
        console.log('starting socketWrapper');

        this.started = true;
        if (!this.sockets.size) {
            this.started = false;
            console.log(`Dashboard service stopped.`);
        }

        //TODO: create event listener
        eventEmitter.on('heartbeat-msg', (msg) => {
            console.log('in eventEmitter.on');
            const ecnStatus = this.parseMessage(msg);
            for (const s of this.sockets) {
                console.log(`Emitting value: ${ecnStatus['ECN']}:${ecnStatus['status']}`);
                s.emit(ecnStatus['ECN'],
                    {
                        'ECN': ecnStatus['ECN'],
                        'status': ecnStatus['status']
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }

    //let's say message comes in as:
    //<ECN>: <status>
    parseMessage(msg) {
        //TODO: return {ECN: <ECN>, status: <status>}
        const res = msg.split(':');
        return {
            'ECN': res[0],
            'status': res[1]
        }
    }
}

module.exports = SocketWrapper;
```

Search for the string `//TODO: create event listener` for relevant part of code.

**Expected:**

```
$ node server.js
Visit http://localhost:8080 in your browser
[12:11:36]
*** Subscriber to topic "tutorial/topic" is ready to connect ***
[12:11:36] Connecting to Solace message router using url: ws://soluatph1v.wellsfargo.net
[12:11:36] Client username: etrade
[12:11:36] Solace message router VPN name: REMOVED
[12:11:36] === Successfully connected and ready to subscribe. ===
[12:11:36] Subscribing to topic: tutorial/topic
[12:11:36] Successfully subscribed to topic: tutorial/topic
[12:11:36] === Ready to receive messages. ===
[12:11:37]
*** Publisher to topic "tutorial/topic" is ready to connect ***
[12:11:37] Connecting to Solace message router using url: REMOVED
[12:11:37] Client username: REMOVED
[12:11:37] Solace message router VPN name: REMOVED
[12:11:37] === Successfully connected and ready to publish messages. ===
[12:11:37] Publishing message "SOM: 0" to topic "tutorial/topic"...
[12:11:37] Message published.
[12:11:37] Disconnecting from Solace message router...
[12:11:37] Disconnected.
[12:11:37] Received message: "SOM: 0", details:
Destination:                            [Topic tutorial/topic]
Class Of Service:                       COS1
DeliveryMode:                           DIRECT
Binary Attachment:                      len=6
  53 4f 4d 3a 20 30                                     SOM:.0

in eventEmitter.on
eventStatus: true
```

What I am looking for is the last two lines of text to demonstrate that the event processing worked.
**Actual:**

```
$ node server.js
Visit http://localhost:8080 in your browser
[12:11:36]
*** Subscriber to topic "tutorial/topic" is ready to connect ***
[12:11:36] Connecting to Solace message router using url: ws://soluatph1v.wellsfargo.net
[12:11:36] Client username: etrade
[12:11:36] Solace message router VPN name: REMOVED
[12:11:36] === Successfully connected and ready to subscribe. ===
[12:11:36] Subscribing to topic: tutorial/topic
[12:11:36] Successfully subscribed to topic: tutorial/topic
[12:11:36] === Ready to receive messages. ===
[12:11:37]
*** Publisher to topic "tutorial/topic" is ready to connect ***
[12:11:37] Connecting to Solace message router using url: REMOVED
[12:11:37] Client username: REMOVED
[12:11:37] Solace message router VPN name: REMOVED
[12:11:37] === Successfully connected and ready to publish messages. ===
[12:11:37] Publishing message "SOM: 0" to topic "tutorial/topic"...
[12:11:37] Message published.
[12:11:37] Disconnecting from Solace message router...
[12:11:37] Disconnected.
[12:11:37] Received message: "SOM: 0", details:
Destination:                            [Topic tutorial/topic]
Class Of Service:                       COS1
DeliveryMode:                           DIRECT
Binary Attachment:                      len=6
  53 4f 4d 3a 20 30                                     SOM:.0

eventStatus: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this question.

Couple things I missed:
1. I never had a socket connection to our server so `socketWrapper.start()` was never called.
2. While doing some primitive testing in `SocketWrapper.js`; i.e.: emitting the event as well as declaring the listener in that file.. I noticed that the listener was being declared **after** the event was emitted. Due to the async nature of node.js, it is important to make sure that things were behaving synchronously.